# Quicktime web rendering issue

Tags: internet-explorer-8, quicktime, render

i have this site i am working on: [www.guygar.com](http://guygar.com/guygar.html)

the quicktime renders the video (legal movie clip) with artifacts.

if i download the video: [clip](http://guygar.com/neo/matrix.mov) then it renders fine, no artifacts.

any idea how can i fixthis?

the site is in IE8 stage presently. but i tried a test run on firefox and the artifacts can be seen there also.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this is a embed quicktime issue as on some machines the video renders fine but on others one can see artifacts.